# Nativescript and Angular routing - URL segment error

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, router-outlet

in my Nativescript/Angular app I have a main module called UsersModule; it contains two modules, UsersListModule and ManageUserModule. This is the structure:
- users

```
- users
   - manageUsers
     * manageUsers-routing.module.ts
     * manageUsers.component.ts
     * manageUsers.component.html
     * manageUsers.module.ts
   - usersList
     * usersList-routing.module.ts
     * usersList.component.ts
     * usersList.component.html
     * usersList.module.ts
 * users-routing.module.ts
 * users-routing.module.html
 * users.component.ts
 * users.module.ts
```

This is the app routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
{ path: "users", loadChildren: "~/app/users/users.module#UsersModule", canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

This the UsersRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "default", component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        { path: "usersList", component: NSEmptyOutletComponent, loadChildren: "~/app/users/usersList/usersList.module#UsersListModule", outlet: "usersList" },
        { path: "manageUsers", component: NSEmptyOutletComponent, loadChildren: "~/app/users/manageUsers/manageUsers.module#ManageUsersModule", outlet: "manageUsers" },
    ]
}
];
```

This is the UsersList routing:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "usersList" },
    { path: "usersList", component: UsersListComponent }
];
```

This is the MangeUsers routing:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "newUser" },
    { path: 'newUser', component: ManageUserComponent },
    { path: 'editUser/:userId', component: ManageUserComponent }
];
```

This is the users.component.html:

```
.....
<page-router-outlet name="usersList"></page-router-outlet>
<page-router-outlet name="manageUsers"></page-router-outlet>
.....
```

The problem is that angular cannot find the segment url and cannot redirect me when I am in the user list and I want to go to edit the selected user. In the UsersListComponent I have this function:

```
  goToEdit(data) {
    let urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree(['../editUser', data.userId], {
        relativeTo: this.activeRoute
    });
    this.routerExtensions.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
};
```

but if I try to go to edit it returns this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'users/default'

And I have a similar issue in the sidenav on users.component, where I try to:

```
    open() {
    this.closeSideDrawer();
    const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree(['/users/newUser'], {
        relativeTo: this.activeRoute
    });
    this.routerExtensions.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
}
```

but if I click, it doesn't redirect, it just closes the sidebar and nothing happens

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground?

Comment: The error simply means that you are trying to access a route that you haven't defined. Without having a sample project setup it's hard to track.